# How to use MATLAB to detect screen changes

Tags: matlab

Hello,

I want to use MATLAB to detect screen changes and **locate the changes**. The changes are third party control. For the time being I can capture the screen using this solution(http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24323-screencapture-get-a-screen-capture-of-a-figure-frame-or-component).

Then the problems remain as follows:

i) How to programmatically get the position vector of the window that I want to monitor

ii) How to compare two screenshots and locate the area of changes

I hope the question is clear. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are more likely to get a response if you elaborate your question. Generally, people like to see that you have coded something, or else they give you negative votes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Shinobii. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Are the windows MATLAB figures or any windows? Do you want to solve i) if that  is possible, and ii) if that isn't directly possible?

Comment: Hi, hbaderts. The windows are any windows. Since I am using MATLAB to do some data processing, it is better to solve it in MATLAB. But any solutions are welcome. Thx.